# android programming for creating animations

Tags: android

i hav displayed the text in a textview.........i want to do animations like rotate etc.......how to do it? which classes are used for it?i want a example program for it?

Answer (score 1):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/RotateAnimation.html

```
RotateAnimation rotate = new RotateAnimation(0f, 90f);
rotate.setDuration(1000);
textView.startAnimation(rotate);
```